# How to use eCryptfs under Google Cloud Shell?

Tags: debian, ecryptfs, google-cloud

I am trying to use `ecryptfs` under [Google Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell). Google Cloud Shell is a virtual machine running **Debian GNU/Linux 9**. I installed `ecryptfs-utils` package using command:

```
sudo apt install ecryptfs-utils
```

After that, I created two new directories:

```
mkdir ~/dir ~/dir.sec
```

And I am trying to mount `dir.sec` on `dir` using:

```
sudo mount -i -t ecryptfs ~/dir.sec ~/dir \
  -o ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32,ecryptfs_passthrough=no,\
ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=no
```

I am getting the following error:

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'ecryptfs'
```